# Unexpected data missing on laravel view with time data

Tags: mysql, laravel, php-carbon

In my Horario Model i have the following:

```
protected $fillable = [ "inicio", "fin", "tipo" ];

protected $dates = [
    'created_at', 
    'updated_at', 
    'inicio', 
    'fin'
];
```

In the controller i save the time as it follows:

```
$horario = new Horario;
$horario->inicio = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $request->inicio);
$horario->fin = Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', $request->fin);
$horario->tipo = $request->tipo;
$horario->save();
```

Where inicio and fin are time type columns, i can save it in the database as it follows (in the format H:i):

[horario record on mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH2KW.png)

When i try to show it in my view laravel throws an error:

```
ErrorException
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing (View: C:\wamp64\www\plataforma-
foodsys\resources\views\opciones_de_aplicacion.blade.php)
```

In my view i have:

```
<td>{{$horario->inicio->format("H:i")}}</td>
<td>{{$horario->fin->format("H:i")}}</td>
```

I can't figure it out why it's throwing the exception, the record are saving just fine on the table and i am trying to format it on the correct time format. Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: have you checked the type of $horario->inicio->format("H:i"); please check it with var_dump();

Comment: It throws me unexpected data found and data missing exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Laravel doesn't recognize 'H:i' format as `date` (as it's not a date).

It will try to convert it to an instance of `Carbon` with [`asDateTime($val)` (source)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Concerns/HasAttributes.php#L679) function, which does not accept `H:i` format.

I'd suggest implementing them as an [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) instead.

Remove `inicio` and `fin` from `protected $dates` array and put this in your model:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;

...

public function getInicioAttribute($val) 
{
    return Carbon::parse($val);
}

public function getFinAttribute($val) 
{
    return Carbon::parse($val);
}
```

And your code should work.

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me, should i try to use a mutator to save it on the model too??